# Tensorflow terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training a resNet50 with tensorflow, using a shared server with these properties:

- ubuntu 16.04
- 3 gtx 1080 gpus
- tensorflow 1.3
- python 2.7

but always after two epochs, and during the third epoch, I encounter this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what():
Resource temporarily unavailable
Aborted (core dumped)
```

with adding some print in my code, I have found where is the problem:

this is convert tfrecord to dataset:

```
filenames = ["balanced_t.tfrecords"]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    def parser(record):
    keys_to_features = {
        # "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "mhot_label_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "mel_spec_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
    }
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

    mel_spec1d = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mel_spec_raw'], tf.float64)
    # label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.string)
    mhot_label = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mhot_label_raw'], tf.float64)
    mel_spec = tf.reshape(mel_spec1d, [96, 64])
    # aa=mel_spec
    return {"mel_data": mel_spec}, mhot_label
    dataset = dataset.map(parser)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(3)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

and this is my input pipline

```
while True:
            try:
               (features, labels) = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
               print("end of training dataset")
```

due to my prints output,the error is for this line:

```
(features, labels) = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

but I dont see any problem,can you help me now?

Comment: It is hard to find the reason with such limited error log. If possible, run your code under `python2.7-dbg` to get a core dump and then upload the core file(usually under `/var/crash` for Ubuntu)

Comment: @ Qmick Zh 
thanks for your reply,I will do with dbg,but now I have found which line cause error,can you help me now?

Comment: @Qmick Zh 
should I use cuda-dbg?because I want to use gpu .

Comment: Most tensorflow error occurs at `sess.run()`. It doesn't give too much information. A `std::system_error` is caused by system call failure under Linux. For example hit limit of #processes, run out of memory etc. I am not sure whether `cuda-dbg` can help in such a situation.

Comment: @ Qmick Zh 
I have upgraded to tensorflow 1.4,but it didnt work,what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked my question in another topic and got my answer:
[stack_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499138/iterator-get-next-cause-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stds)

It was about my tensorflow code,It was some kind of memory leak