# iterator.get_next() cause terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am training a resNet50 with tensorflow, using a shared server with these properties:

ubuntu 16.04
3 gtx 1080 gpus
tensorflow 1.3
python 2.7
but always after two epochs, and during the third epoch, I encounter this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' 
what():
Resource temporarily unavailable
Aborted
```

this is code convert tfrecord to dataset:

```
filenames = ["balanced_t.tfrecords"]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
def parser(record):
keys_to_features = {
    "mhot_label_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, 
default_value=""),
    "mel_spec_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, 
default_value=""),
}
parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

mel_spec1d = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mel_spec_raw'], tf.float64)
# label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.string)
mhot_label = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mhot_label_raw'], tf.float64)
mel_spec = tf.reshape(mel_spec1d, [96, 64])
return {"mel_data": mel_spec}, mhot_label
dataset = dataset.map(parser)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(3)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

and this is input pipline:

```
while True:
        try:
           (features, labels) = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
           print("end of training dataset")
```

After inserting some print message in my code,Ihave discovered that the below line cause this error:

```
(features, labels) = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

But,I cant solve it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code has a (subtle) memory leak, so it's possible that the process is running out of memory and being terminated. The issue is that calling `iterator.get_next()` in each loop iteration will add a new node to the TensorFlow graph, which will end up consuming a lot of memory.

To stop the memory leak, rewrite your `while` loop as the following:

```
# Call `get_next()` once outside the loop to create the TensorFlow operations once.
next_element = iterator.get_next()

while True:
    try:
        (features, labels) = sess.run(next_element)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("end of training dataset")
```